# Center a matrix

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to center this board, this is the code, I tried with %*s, but it didn't work out.
Any idea?

```
board = [["1","2","2"],["8*1","2@3","5*6"],["9","5","8"],["2","2","2"],
     ["5*6","6*8","0@2"],["1","2","8"],["1","9","8"],["2*7","7*5","4@2"],["1","3","3"]]

counter = 0

print("--------------+---------------+-------------------")

for row in board:
    counter += 1
    print("|"      "%s"     "|") % ("       |      ".join(row).center(47))
    if counter == 3 or counter == 6 or counter == 9:
        print("---------------+---------------------+--------------")
```

the output should be like this for every box

```
        +-----------+
        | 1 | 1 | 9 |

        |2@3|1*6|7*2|

        | 4 | 1 | 2 |
        +-----------+
```

Comment: Your output example does not fit with your code. Please explain what you want in more detail.

Comment: Your center line does the whole row; it appears that you need to center each cell (e.g. center 3 times on each row)

Comment: what I am trying to do is a board, which has 9 boxes. Every box has three lines, and the end of the box is marked with a line,in this case ---------

Comment: `if counter == 3 or counter == 6 or counter == 9` -> `if counter in (3, 6, 9)`

Comment: @Maria I think you could shorten it even more to: `if counter % 3 == 0:`

Comment: @Maria Also use `str.format` from now on instead of `%` since that has been deprecated :D

Comment: @jamylak Good thinking!, Any good tutorial on str.format, that can help me with this topic? Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @Maria I just used this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/ Not sure which is the best though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to produce something close to what you asked for:

```
board = [["1","2","2"],["8*1","2@3","5*6"],["9","5","8"],
         ["2","2","2"],["5*6","6*8","0@2"],["1","2","8"],
         ["1","9","8"],["2*7","7*5","4@2"],["1","3","3"]]

counter = 0

print("+-----------+")

for row in board:
    counter += 1
    print("|%s|" % "|".join(c.center(3) for c in row))
    if counter == 3 or counter == 6 or counter == 9:
        print("+-----------+")
```

which produces:

```
+-----------+
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
|8*1|2@3|5*6|
| 9 | 5 | 8 |
+-----------+
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
|5*6|6*8|0@2|
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
+-----------+
| 1 | 9 | 8 |
|2*7|7*5|4@2|
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: @jamylak, wow, you're kind of annoying. I just made minimal changes to the user's code to get it working. The changes you made really weren't all that great. I guess that's just what some people like to do.

Comment: I want to promote good python coding practices, I don't really care if it annoys you.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want, I believe:

```
board=[["1","2","2"],["8*1","2@3","5*6"],["9","5","8"],["2","2","2"],
["5*6","6*8","0@2"],["1","2","8"],["1","9","8"],["2*7","7*5","4@2"],["1","3","3"]]
counter=0

print ("----------------+---------------+----------------")

for row in board:
        counter+=1
        s="|"
        for column in row:
                s += column.center(15) + "|"
        print(s)
        if counter==3 or counter==6 or counter==9:
                print ("----------------+---------------+----------------")
```

Output:

```
----------------+---------------+----------------
|       1       |       2       |       2       |
|      8*1      |      2@3      |      5*6      |
|       9       |       5       |       8       |
----------------+---------------+----------------
|       2       |       2       |       2       |
|      5*6      |      6*8      |      0@2      |
|       1       |       2       |       8       |
----------------+---------------+----------------
|       1       |       9       |       8       |
|      2*7      |      7*5      |      4@2      |
|       1       |       3       |       3       |
----------------+---------------+----------------
```

Comment: @jamylak: thanks, still learning Python :) there are some nice tweaks!

Answer (score 1):

```
("|"      "%s"     "|")
```

This is three string literals: `"|"`, `"%s"` and `"|"`, separated by spaces. Python will join them together at compile time, because they are literals (and not variables that happen to contain strings; that kind of analysis can't be done at compile time). So the whole thing is equivalent to "|%s|".

If you want the space to be included in the string, then include the space in the string: "|         %s       |", with whatever number of spaces are needed on each side. Alternatively, use string multiplication and addition operations to construct the string: `"|" + " " * n + "%s" + " " * n + "|"`, for example, where `n` is whatever number of spaces you need on each side.